# SQL Error while using v.distance through simple python editor in grass

Tags: python, grass-gis, grass-7.4

I try to execute the following code:

```
grass.run_command('v.distance', from='tramstop', to='iso_tram', upload='cat',column='first_tram_distance', overwrite=True)
```

but i get the "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" Error.
I guess using 'from' is colliding with SQL, yet since it is required as an input parameter I have no idea how to work around the issue. Using "from" with quotation marks doesnt work, since "keyword can't be an expression".

I would be very happy if anyone knows how to fix this problem.

Comment: I believe that the error is from python (not GRASS). Do you have the grass script module loaded? i.e. `import grass.script as grass`.  Can you run `grass.version()` ? Maybe some typo in the line *preceding* the above ?

Comment: Hey there, yes everything is loaded and working. I am very sure the problem is with the key-word "from". I could bypass the problem through sending the line to the console, yet this feels like a dirty solution :( : `os.system( " ".join(["v.distance","from=tramstop","to=iso_tram","upload=cat","column=first_tram_distance","--o"])) `

Comment: I guess this works, because now "from" is in a string and sql doesnt complain..

Comment: You can always "escape" SQL reserved words with an underscore suffix. Can you try:  `...  from_="tramstop", ...`

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution was exactly what i was hoping for :). Now my question is answered.